# Display each subjects to different buttons

Tags: php, arrays

[image: Collapse button]

I want to display each subjects to different buttons, I tried using `explode` and `implode` function but it didn't worked. [image]

This is how I saved the subjects. I saved all the subjects as a string. And converted it to array and string before displaying.

Here's my code.

```
<?php
                $id = $_GET['id'];

                $s = "SELECT * FROM enrollment WHERE stud_id = '$id'";
                $q = mysqli_query($conn, $s);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
                        $subjects = $row['stud_subjects'];
            ?>
            
            <button class="collapsible">
                <?php
                    $sub = explode(", ", $subjects);
                    $subs = implode("<br>", $sub);
                    echo $subs;
                ?>
            </button>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: What does `print_r($subjects)` look like?

Comment: It showing same result

Comment: It's not really clear what output you're expecting here. You've split on comma, and then joined with `<br>`, which is a line break, so you have the names on different lines.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused what to do. I just want to display each subjects on different buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have posted, something like this should get you closer to what you want:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$s = "SELECT * FROM enrollment WHERE stud_id = '$id'";
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $s);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
        $subjects = $row['stud_subjects'];

        $sub = explode(', ', $subjects);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($subjects); $i++) {
            echo "<button class='collapsible'> " . $subs[$i] . "</button>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Basically, once you get the `$subjects` and break them up into an array instead of a comma separated list, you can loop through the array and echo out the button with the subject name of the `$ith` element from `$subs`.